# What does this piece of code do? a = (a == b) ? c: b;

Tags: javascript

```
a = (a == b) ? c: b;
```

I don't understand. All of them {a, b, c} are variables set with certain value by the programmer.

Comment: If **a** is equals to **b** then assigns **c** to **a** else **b**.

Comment: There's the same operator in other languages, but one thing to keep in mind with javascript, the conditional part of the ternary operator (the `(a == b)` in this example), is "truthy", not just simple booleans. So `99 ? "a" : "b"` will return "a", and `0 ? "a" : "b"` will return "b". This can let you do some cool stuff with this operator in javascript (just like you can with the `||` operator).

Comment: if a is equal to be then a equals c , else a equals b .

Answer (score 4):

That is called the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx): that is the same as doing:

```
if(a == b)
 a = c;
else
 a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `a` equals `b` then `a` = `c` otherwise `a` = `b`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short form for an if and an assignment.

q = x ? y : z

q is the variable you assign to
x is a boolean expression which will be true or false.
If it is true y will be assigned to your variable q
else z will be assigned to q.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is equivalent to:

```
if (a == b) {
  a = c;
} else {
  a = b;
}
```

The main difference is that `if/else` consists of conditional statements, while the ternary operator is a conditional expression. In other words, the ternary operator works as if the if/else were returning a value. In some other languages, `if/else` are expressions as well, so the following would be valid, and indeed equivalent to `?:` :

```
a = (if (a == b) { c; } else { b; }) // not valid javascript
```

Be sure to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

The Mozilla Developer Network is a fantastic reference for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if `a` equal to `b` then assign `c` to `a` , otherwise assign `b` to `a`

Answer (score 0):

In english -

```
If a is equal to b, then a = c. otherwise, a = b
```

Answer (score 0):

The ?: syntax is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Essentially it means that if `a` is equal to `b` than `a` equals `c` otherwise `a` equals `b`